# Not empty omega limit set

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Dynamical system is generated by:

$x'=-x+f(x,y)$
$y'=-y+g(x,y)$

$f,g \in C^1$ and $f,g$ are bounded.

Prove that the *omega limit set of p:*  $\omega(p) \neq \emptyset$ for all $p \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

---

I can say that if $f_{y}g_{x} \in (0,1)$ Jacobian \begin{pmatrix}-1&f_{y}\\g_{x}&-1\\ \end{pmatrix} has negative eigenvalues, and $\omega(p) = (0,0)$ for all $p \in \mathbb{R}^2$. But it's not much...

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ and $g$ are bounded this means that the solutions to the system are bounded. If the solutions are bounded then $\omega$-limit set is nonempty since in any bounded sequence a convergent subsequence can be found, and the limit of this subsequence belongs to $\omega$-limit set.