# Existence of invariant set in dynamical system generated by ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, set-invariance

Is there any nonempty, compact and invariant set in dynamical system generated by this system of equations?

$x'=x+\sin{(xy+2)}-7$
$y'=-y+\arctan{(x^2+y^3-6)}$

---

My idea is to use this fact: [Not empty omega limit set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257571/not-empty-omega-limit-set) - because here we have also bounded functions and *omega limit set* is invariant. But it's hard to say anything about compactness.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Edit: Of course is not true that omega limit set is always invariant - it is only when it lays in trajectory. That makes problem harder and probably it's not a good way.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: a fixed point is a compact invariant set.  If that fixed point has a stable manifold, you can include some of that too.

Comment: Thank you. Now I have to solve $x+\sin{(xy+2)}-7=0 $,   $-y+\arctan{(x^2+y^3-6)}=0$

Comment: Don't try for a "closed form" solution, but show there is a solution in, say, the rectangle $6 \le x \le 8$, $-\pi/2 \le y \le \pi/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Not only that. If you find a bounded trajectory then its closure is also an invariant set. (It can only be made the trajectory and fixed points). I suggest you try to run it through a numerical program so you get the feel of the system.